# Different ways of setting properties in Ember

Tags: ember.js

What is the difference between:

```
myObject.set('some_property', 'myvalue');
```

and

```
Ember.set(myObject,'some_property', 'myvalue');
```

I am using the first syntax, but I noticed, that many people use the second one with Ember.set(). So what is the difference here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Igor,

`myObject.set()` vs `Ember.set(myObject..)` matters only if `myObject` is unknown.

If you are getting myObject as user input, then it's always better to use `Ember.set(myObject, 'some_property', 'myValue') since we will not be sure if myObject is empty or not. For example:

```
let myObject = {};
myObject.set('some_property', 'myValue');
```

Output will be: Uncaught TypeError: myObject.set is not a function(…). However, if use `Ember.set`, then

```
let myObject = {};
Ember.set(myObject, 'some_property', 'myValue');
```

The property will be set without throwing any error.

So, the ember tip would be to use `Ember.set` if the JS object is unknown otherwise, you can use `.set()`.

Stefan Penner had given an amazing explanation regarding this in reddit. Here is the link: https://www.reddit.com/r/emberjs/comments/3mr5as/question_why_use_embergetthis_prop_instead_of/

Hope it helps.